# Creating rasters?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, grass-gis

I am doing my masters in archaeology, but have used GIS for some time now, however this is my first attempt at generating and using rasters. I appear to have been successful for some, but not so well for others. All the books and tutorials I have looked at don't really explain what the different values are when creating a raster and I'm unsure if I should be changing the default values to something else to produce the image I want and if I am to change them what to? I could spend a life time changing the values, but still wouldn't be sure I understood what they did.

Can anyone recommend a book, blog, tutorial that would help me with this?

I am using GRASS, QGIS and ArcMap/Scene, but if there is another program out there that could be useful I'm willing to try.

Thanks

Christina

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Could you list the parameters you are having trouble with? Also, this site is a Q&A site where each thread should contain only one question and its answers. You have two pretty independent questions. Therefore, please move the second one to a new thread.

Comment: Re the second question: start with https://www.google.com/search?q=raster+terrain+analysis.

Comment: What is the purpose of the raster you want to create, what information will it convey / contain?

Comment: I am having issues with the output of the cell size, search radius weight, and the power value etc.

Comment: The purpose of the ratser is to identify new archaeological features, which appear in the landscape as depressions. And from the raster I would like to be able to calculate their size and shape. If that is possible?

Answer (score 1):

To extract terrain parameters from a DEM like depressions, you can use [r.param.scale](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.param.scale.html).

Concerning further reading: I can recommend this book for detailed insights and also for a comparative software overview: [Geomorphometry: Concepts, Software, Applications](http://www.geomorphometry.org/book). Edited by Tomislav Hengl and Hannes I. Reuter (2009)